# wso2is any way to code claim to return static text

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When using WSO2 Identity server I need to return static text to one service provider.  This text is used by the service provider to identify which tenant our users are associated with.

Is there a way to code a claim to always return a specific text?

Thanks,
...pat

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to identify the tenant which the user belongs, you can retrieve the tenant domain with subject identifier. Enable 'Use tenant domain in local subject identifier ' in the 'Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration' section of the service provider. You can find more details from the documentation in [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider