# Can I define static claims to be returned to a Service Provider?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a use-case where a SAML2 application expects certain attributes in the SAML2 assertion. These are not present in user attributes, but they should have static values which are returned in every SAML2 assertion for that service provider.

Is there any way to define such static attributes/claims in WSO2 IS admin console? I know I could create a custom claims handler with Java, but I'm looking first for solutions not requiring custom code.

This issue was similar, but the answer didn't apply to the general case: [wso2is any way to code claim to return static text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848825/wso2is-any-way-to-code-claim-to-return-static-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Adaptive Authentication script for this. (Simple scripting supported via Management Console)

Example :

```
function onLoginRequest(context) {
executeStep(1, {
    onSuccess: function (context) {
        var user = context.currentKnownSubject;
        var countryClaim = 'http://wso2.org/claims/country';
        var countryValue = user.localClaims[countryClaim];
        if (countryValue == null){
            Log.info('Updating the address - country claim for user.');
            context.steps[1].subject.localClaims[countryClaim] = 'Canada';
        }
        Log.info('Testing of adding default claim value to user.');
    }
});
```

}

Documentation

1. [Adaptive Authentication](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/adaptive-authentication/)
2. [Adaptive Authentication JS API Reference](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/)